# Proving two subobjects are equal

Tags: category-theory

I don't think I can really represent this problem properly without quoting precisely what I was given:

> Prove that, for any object $A$ in a category $\mathscr{C}$, and any subobjects $M, N \in Sub_\mathscr{C} (A)$, show that $M=N$ if and only if, for every generalized element $x : X \rightarrow A$, $z \in_A M$ if and only if $z \in_A N$.

A footnote: I believe the use of $z$ is a typo and $x$ was intended, but I could be wrong since I don't feel I have the firmest grip on subobjects yet.

---

**Problem I'm Having #1:**

I feel that the double "if and only if's" are tripping me up, I'm not 100% on how to contend with them. My initial instinct is that we're to prove:

- $(\Rightarrow)$ $M=N$ implies, for all subobjects $x : X \rightarrow A$, $x \in_A M$ implies $x \in_A N$, and $x \in_A N$ implies $x \in_A M$.
- $(\Leftarrow)$ For all subobjects $x : X \rightarrow A$, when $x \in_A M$ implies $x \in_A N$, and $x \in_A N$ implies $x \in_A M$, these imply $M =N$.

But I'm very uncertain about this; I think this is the first time I've ever seen double if-and-only-if statements in a theorem.

---

**Problem I'm Having #2:**

If I understand the definition of subobject correctly, then a subobject of $A$ is any monic arrow with codomain $A$, and the local membership relation "$\in_A$" means that $x \in_A M$ if and only if there exists $f : X \rightarrow M$ such that $m \circ f = x$, i.e. the triangle below commutes

[image]

I just want to make sure that these definitions are correct because I'm not even 100% where to get started, at least on the latter implication (if I'm somehow right).

Comment: To help with the parsing of the iffs, consider the statement in the category of sets, with X
being the one-element set, so that a generalized element is just an element. Given two subsets $M$ and $N$ of $A$, we have: ($M=N$) iff (every $x \in M$ belongs in $N$ and every $x \in N$ belongs in M). From my reading, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is correct as you write. 
The subobjects are rather *equivalence classes* of monomorphisms:

> We regard monomorphisms $m:M\to A$ and $n:N\to A\ $ as *the same* subobject of $A$,
>   $\ \ $  if there is an isomorphism $i:M\to N$ such that $n\circ i=m$.

For the sake of clarity, let $\ \sim\ $ denote this equivalence relation on the set of monomorphisms to $A$.
(By the way, the given notation is very sloppy. If we want to be precise, $M$ is only the domain of a representative monomorphism of the subobject we're talking about; however $M=N$ is used in this context to mean $m\sim n$)

More generally, there's a natural preorder, defining $m\le n$ by the same condition without requiring $i$ to be isomorphism, which corresponds to the usual *inclusion* of subobjects, and we have $m\sim n\ $ if and only if $\ m\le n$ and $n\le m$.

You can also prove the corresponding statement about generalized elements for inclusions. Then the equality of subobjects will immediately follow.

Comment: Now see, I was under the impression that we were talking about the domains $M,N$ being equal since I think we were told that the subobject would be the pairing of the monic arrow as well as its domain. (Similar to the equalizer.) This actually does reframe it in an interesting way, though, I'll have to try that.